# qt4-embedded executable error: No such file or directory

Tags: yocto, openembedded, qtembedded

I am using qt4-embedded version 4.7.8 to cross-compile applications for arm7l target. I have configured qt correctly but once I launch the executable on the target, I am getting this error:
"no such file or directory"
What am I doing wrong?
My development environment is linux ubuntu 16.04, my cross-compiler is arm-linux-gnueabi.
The target is 32 bit.
I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: it may be because the executable is of the wrong format (e.g. build for wrong architecture). what does the `file` say?

Comment: please show the complete error. this is mostly because you didn't set up the SDK correctly.

Comment: That could be true.Do you mind helping me set up the sdk?